# ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm getting an error: `ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.`

The shape of X is (138,4) and y is (138,). This error occurs when the grid.fit(X,y) method is called. Please help me resolve the error

```
xls_file = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Book1.xls', sheetname='Sheet1', header=1)
# Create Variables. All the X and y values are picked from the excel files and converted to numpy arrays

wellno = xls_file.iloc[:, 0].values
T = xls_file.iloc[:, 1].values
Rs = xls_file.iloc[:, 6].values
API = xls_file.iloc[:, 2].values
gamma_g = xls_file.iloc[:, 3].values
Pb = xls_file.iloc[:, 4].values
Bo = xls_file.iloc[:, 5].values

y = Pb
X = np.c_[T, Rs, gamma_g, API]

X_2d = X[:, :2]
y_2d = y

C_range = np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: It would be good to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Show the number of different labels in y using np.unique(y) This error arises because there is only 1 type of class in `y` when `grid.fit` is called.

Comment: Thank you Vivek, your comment could very well point to the solution I needed.